# synchronize object tree from server to client using ServiceStack

Tags: c#, rest, servicestack

I have a tree of objects on my server. In essence, it's a map made up of layers, and each map layer is made of map shapes. I want this tree duplicated to my client. I'm using the Servicestack framework.

Currently I poll from the client to the server. With each poll request I send the timestamp returned in my previous poll. The server then sends me objects that have changed since that time. In order to know that items on the client need to be removed I've been sending the entire object ID tree with each poll. Merging the received tree with updates into the full tree on the client is somewhat painful and requires sending more data than is necessary.

What other suggestions do you have for synchronizing complex objects from the server to the client? Are there any existing frameworks for this? Both my client and server use C#.